# Cannot Play "m4a" in swift 2.

Tags: ios, swift2, avfoundation

I am new to swift. I am trying to run an audio file using avfoundation in swift 2. This codes run for file format "mp3" but xcode crashes for "m4a". Whats my mistake? I am using xcode 7.3.1.

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
 var myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let myFilePathString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Par30", ofType:"m4a")

    if let myFilePathString = myFilePathString
    {
        let myFilePathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myFilePathString)


        do{

            try myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: myFilePathURL)

            //myAudioPlayer.play()

        }catch
        {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func Play(sender: AnyObject) {

    myAudioPlayer.play()

}


@IBAction func Stop(sender: AnyObject) {

    myAudioPlayer.stop()
    myAudioPlayer.currentTime = 0
  }
```

}

Comment: It would be helpful if you included any error that got printed out.  There's no obvious reason this should fail (except that your M4A file isn't really in that format perhaps).  You could try ffprobe or a similar utility to see what it really is.

Comment: build succeeded but when I press on play button app crashes and print (lldb)